# What is the difference between rhino-mocks stub and expect

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks, stub, stubbing, expectations

What is the difference between rhino-mocks stub and expect here: Looks to me that they behave exact the same?

```cs
mockContext.Stub(x => x.Find<Blog>())
    .Return(new List<Blog>() 
    { 
        new Blog() { Id = 1, Title = "Test" } 
    }.AsQueryable());

mockContext.Expect(x => x.Find<Blog>())
    .Return(new List<Blog>()
    {
        new Blog(){Id = 1,Title = "Title"},
        new Blog(){Id=2,Title = "no"}
    }.AsQueryable());
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Stub()` defines **the behavior** for stubbed object.
`Expect()` defines **the behavior** and **the expectation** for mocked object.

So if you need to check that mocked method was called you should use `Expect`:

```cs
var mockContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IContext>();
mockContext.Expect(x => x.Find<Blog>()).Return(new List<Blog>());
```

Now after *test action* complete you are able to verify that expectaions are met:

```cs
mockContext.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

If you need to stub method behavior you can use `Stub()`:

```cs
var mockContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IContext>();
mockContext.Stub(x => x.Find<Blog>()).Return(new List<Blog>());
```

Comment: Expect() is important so that developer can put the code to verify the expectation. Incase that .Find<Blog>() function is removed, then VerifyAllExpectations() can track that. Stub can't.

If you are not verifying the expectations, you can just use stub.

Answer (score 2):

When you use Expect for a method in this case x.Find(), if your method is not called during the test mockContext.VerifyAllExpectations(); will fail.